# Using log4j in Tomcat with different Appenders

Tags: logging, log4j, tomcat7

I have configured Tomcat to use the log4j logger like it is explained here: 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Everything is working fine except of the logging mechanism of a class of the webbapp. It isn't logging anything for some reason....

I am experiencing following warning:

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (WEBAPP).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

My log4j.properies (located in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`)looks like that:

```
 log4j.rootLogger = INFO,CATALINA,LOCALHOST,CONSOLE,WEBAPP

 # Define all the appenders
 log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8

 log4j.appender.WEBAPP=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.File=${catalina.base}/logs/actions
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.MaxFileSize=4MB
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.MaxBackupIndex=9
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.Append = true
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.Encoding=UTF-8
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.WEBAPP.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss} [[%5p] %c [%t]] %m%n
 log4j.category.WEBAPP=INFO
 log4j.additivity.WEBAPP=false

 # Roll-over the log once per day
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

 log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

 log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

 # Configure which loggers log to which appenders
 log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
 log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] =\INFO, MANAGER
 log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] =\INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

I want to write the actions taking place in the webapp in a special log file  called '*actions*', but the log file wasn't even created. The webapp is running on the tomcat and it is working nice except the logging.
In the classes of the webapp, which should be logged into the log file, there are loggers initialized like that:

```
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("WEBAPP");
```

I thought it would be enough but it isn't working...

Any advice would be nice and thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Solved it! I just added *WEBAPP* to `log4j.category.WEBAPP=INFO`. Separated with a coma and now it is finally working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! 
I just added WEBAPP to `log4j.category.WEBAPP=INFO`. Separated with a coma and now it is finally working....

So, do this
`log4j.category.WEBAPP=INFO, WEBAPP` 
instead of this
`log4j.category.WEBAPP=INFO`
and it is finally working. :-)